# Include <link> in GPX when writing from ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, gpx

http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html seems to indicate that ogr2ogr should be able to write `<link>`[1] elements into a GPX file, however when using ogr2ogr to convert from PostGIS to GPX, I get the message,

```
Field of name 'link_href' is not supported in GPX schema. Use GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS creation option to allow use of the <extensions> element.
```

I've tried naming the field, link, href, link_href and link0_href, but none work. Any hints?

[1] http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_linkType

Update: Looking at the sources http://sources.debian.net/src/gdal/1.10.1%2Bdfsg-8/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/gpx/ogrgpxlayer.cpp/ it doesn't seem like it supports writing  elements, only reading, is this correct?